# how do i return json object in action result in mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a method of action result in a controller where i have some conditions if the conditions fails then i want to send a json object to the view but i am not able to do it. can any one help me out.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Loginuser(LoginDetails newlogin)
    {
        LoginDetails objlogin = new LoginDetails();
        objlogin.UserEmail = newlogin.UserEmail;
        objlogin.UserPassword = newlogin.UserPassword;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                RegisterBAL Regball = new RegisterBAL();
                objlogin = Regball.LoginUserBAL(objlogin);
                if(objlogin.ResponseCode == "000")
                {
                    if(objlogin.UserRole =="CityHelpdesk")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("CityHelpdesk", "RoleDashbord");
                    }
                    if (objlogin.UserRole == "CityAdmin")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("CityAdmin", "RoleDashbord");
                    }
                    if (objlogin.UserRole == "StateAdmin")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("StateAdmin", "RoleDashbord");
                    }
                    if (objlogin.UserRole == "StateHelpdesk")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("StateHelpdesk", "RoleDashbord");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return json object//// Hear i want to return the json object
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            objlogin.ResponseCode = "EXC";
        }

    }
```

Comment: `return Json(objlogin, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Just `return Json(objlogin);` (`JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is only needed on a GET method) but its not clear why you would want to display a new view that just shows json

Comment: @StephenMuecke, OK, Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 4):

You can return Json via the `return Json()` method

For your situation, that would be `return Json(objlogin);`

Be aware that you will be posting the username and password back to the client. Better filter out the fields that you need and return a new model

Answer (score 1):

You can Use:

```
return NotFound({JsonObject})
```

Or

```
return BadRequest({JsonObject})
```

Or

```
return Ok({JsonObject})
```

Or

```
return Content("String")
```